# R: How to create ggplot based timeline

Tags: r, ggplot2, timeline

I need ggplot based timeline. Something similar to gvisTimeline but simplified. Currently there is no way to install more packages, so I am limited to what I already have.

I need to visualize multiple events (around 40) with start and end in around 12 hours. Overlapping and with different duration. The data looks like

```
Name,Start,End
event1,08/04/2020 17:45:18,08/04/2020 18:45:18 
event2,08/04/2020 20:45:18,08/04/2020 21:00:18 
event3,08/04/2020 21:00:00,09/04/2020 00:30:18 
.
.
.
```

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the easiest way to do this is by hacking a boxplot:

```r
ggplot(df, aes(x = Name, y = Start, fill = Name)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(lower = Start, ymin = Start, ymax = End, upper = End, middle = End), 
               stat = "identity", width=0.5) + 
  coord_flip()
```

[image]

Comment: This looks very promising! :)

Comment: I am receiving an error:

Error: Can't draw more than one boxplot per group. Did you forget aes(group = ...)?

My dates are in POSIXct to be date and time.

Comment: @YavorI is this perhaps because not all of your events have unique names?

Comment: You are right! :)
Is there a way to have 2 events with the same name but in different times (they can be in the same line )

Comment: @YavorI there is a way, but it is more complex. You would need to use `geom_rect` to do this, and create dummy y variables to set the upper and lower borders of the box, as well as manually labelling the axis. It's possible,

Comment: It will be easier to modify the data and to put unique event names. Thanks for your help!

Comment: One final question - how to modify the time axis, to have more adequate ticks - every hour for example?

Comment: @YavorI you can do this via ggplot's  `scale_y_datetime` - it has tons of options. Check out `?scale_y_datetime`

Comment: Very useful. Thanks